# ffmpeg throwing System.AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, .net-core, ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg to extract frames and iterate over them. The codes iterates correctly over few frames and then  then randomly throws error

```
"System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve it? System details and screenshot below:

System Details:
OS: Windows
TargetFramework: .netCore3.1
Nugets: FFMediaToolkit v3.0.0 and SixLabors.ImageSharp v1.0.0
Shared dlls copied from: https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/ for version 4.2.2

[image: ErrorScreenshot]

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: It is in a c# console application.

Comment: We will need to see your code. At the moment, you're effectively saying "there's a bug with ffmpeg, how can I work around it?". There might be, but it's more likely that there's a bug with how *you're* using ffmpeg. As such, we will need to see a small demo which exhibits the bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with this library but from the stack trace it seems that you close an AVFormatContext which is possible already closed or not initialized yet. Review your code and make sure that you don't do that. Worst case you could also try to add the following above your function and discard the exception:-

```
[HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]
[SecurityCritical]
void avcloseinputFunction() {
try { avformat_close_input ... } catch (Exception e) {}
}
```